# Reading IIS error logs - status and substatus

Tags: 500-error, iis-8, http-status-code

While trying to troubleshoot an IIS error I came upon a guide that discussed the error code in the IIS log.

[The 4 server logs you NEED to know to fix any IIS / ASP.NET error](http://blog.leansentry.com/2013/07/the-server-logs-you-need-to-know-to-fix-any-iis-aspnet-error)

The post uses the following excerpt from an IIS log file ...

```
2013-06-16 03:39:19 ::1 GET /test.aspx mincase=80 80 - ::1 - 500 16 0 3173
```

The article goes on to say that the 500 represents the status code while the 16 is the substatus code. However, when I try and search for the status code via Google, I always see it referred to as `500.16`. Is this essentially two different ways to reference the same error code? Is there a difference between and `500 16` and `500.16`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different ways of saying the same thing, yes.

For what it's worth, the 500.16 way of doing it is preferable, for being easier to search and organize, and a lot of error codes are done this way, for the same reason.  http error codes, for example.